# How to download/install/configure a pre-installed Ubuntu image

Tags: drivers, dell

I'm planning on buying a Dell with pre-installed Ubuntu image.

In case something goes wrong, how do I reinstall Ubuntu from scratch with the Dell's image containing all of Dell's specific drivers?

I couldn't even find a downloadable image on [Dell's site](http://www.dell.com/support/home/il/en/ilbsdt1/product-support/product/latitude-14-5480-laptop/drivers) :-(

Comment: "In case something goes wrong, how do I reinstall Ubuntu from scratch with the Dell's image containing all of Dell's specific drivers? " Check for a recovery partition. Mind though that it is far better not to depend on the OEM install and plan your own install.

Comment: @Rinzwind why is it "better not to depend on the OEM install and plan your own install"?

Comment: Because the OEM install is likely an LTS. If you want a non-LTS installed when it releases the oem is useless: you will not find an oem to install. If your system is still useful after the LTS ends the same (even though that is a lengthy 5 years). So use a normal install and make note of the changes you need to make to install (if there are any) and anything special you might need and just install those yourself. You will learn about your system and learn about Ubuntu. Never a bad idea.